# View function with args

Tags: nearprotocol

I've managed to call a view function without args and got the expected result. But when trying to call it with args, I get errors depending on how I call it. I have

```
args = '{"account_id":"account.testnet"}'
```

and when calling

```
await account.viewFunction(
    contract,
    method,
    args
)
```

I  get "Contract method calls expect named arguments wrapped in object, e.g. { argName1: argValue1, argName2: argValue2 }

Thinking it meant an object, I converted args using JSON.parse(args), but now I get the error "Account ID too short". Logging the new args I get:

```
{account_id: 'account.testnet'}
```

So I'm guessing the ' is closing the JSON at some point

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell to call the function try to use a different command-line shell like bash.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem:

I was getting the contract from another file. I set the structure but never properly set the values, so contract was the empty string and thus the error.

Hope this silly mistake is helpful for someone